# inserting json data in meteor collection

Tags: json, insert, meteor

Here's my code. https://github.com/StudioMockingbird/SH_meteor

its just the leaderboard example wwhere i am trying to insert some of my own data in the collections.

my data resides in lib/book.js and has been defined as an object (var myBook).

the code that I use for inserting is in leaderboard.js as -

```
Pages = new Meteor.Collection("pages");
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        if(Pages.find().count() === 0){
            var pages = JSON.parse(myBook.stories);
            for (page in pages) {
                Pages.insert(pages[page]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

when i try to run my code it gives me

```
Running on: http://localhost:3000/
Exited with code: 1
Exited with code: 1
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

what am I doing wrong? I am totally new to meteor.

Comment: If meteor is just starting up wouldn't myBook be undefined at that point when its being inserted

Comment: i have put my data in a js file in the lib folder. so the var gets initialized immediately in. If in the same code block, i do a console.log, i can see the myBook data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to iron out:

**Remove the scoping of your book**

You've used `var myBook`, by using `var` the `myBook` variable is being scoped, or at least it is with my `0.6.0` rc8, if you're getting the book with console.log don't worry about this now, but if you run into it later if `0.6.0` gives you problems just change it around

**Using JSON.parse**

You don't need to parse your JSON data into an object as its already declared as one so change:

```
 var pages = JSON.parse(myBook.stories);
```

to

```
var pages = myBook.stories;
```

With those changes I've managed to get it to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Or another way with 'forEach`. I would prefer it because it is 'async'

```
pages.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    console.log('inserting book ', item);
    Pages.insert(
        item
    );
});
```